# Is there a WPF Cheat Sheet available?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm looking for a WPF cheat sheet that has the WPF markup extensions for binding, resources, and other common things in WPF.  But so far I've had trouble finding it.

Anyone know where I could find one?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I wrote a cheat sheet specifically for data binding and posted it on my blog at:

http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2009/02/02/wpf-xaml-data-binding-cheat-sheet.aspx

It's very detailed and covers all the properties of the Binding class (because I never forget how to write {StaticResource something} but how to one-way bind to an ancestor of the target element is another thing).

Comment: Thanks Nir, very good cheat sheet for binding related stuff, this will definitely get posterized. Too bad I can't accept more than one answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Nir - this is a great resource that's been passed around quite a lot in the WPF community. I've made some revisions and additions (I hope you don't mind) which I have on Google Docs here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzfY1xYjsjYbOXdGV0RGZDNHM0k

Answer (score 31):

I have created a cheat sheet an have posted it on my blog at:

http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/02/01/xaml-for-wpf-cheatsheet-10-draft/

it is only a draft (currently in word the final will be in PDF) and I am looking for feedback on how to improve it.

**UPDATE:** Final PDF copy can be now found here:

http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/02/03/xaml-for-wpf-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thanks John, that is really cool of you :). Cheers.

Comment: Great. Please note, typo: "SoldColorBrush" instead of Solid...

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the binding cheat sheet and found this thread. I manage a chart of the common WPF types. It's available [here](http://kittencode.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/wpf-class-hierarchy-diagram-1-2/)

[image: Version 1.2]

Answer (score 4):

In advance of the imminent Visual Studio 2010 release, I put together a quick reference wall chart that may be of interest. On a single page I compare and contrast the ***toolbox-centric features*** of:

- Visual Studio 2008 vs. 2010
- .Net 3.5 vs. 4.0
- WinForm vs. WPF

My article about the implications of this wallchart is available on [Simple-Talk.com](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/from-winform-to-wpf-a-quick-reference-guide/). In the "bubble" at the top of the article you will find links to the wallchart in PDF form, provided in both LTR and A4 sizes.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a XAML cheatsheet which is currently focussing on Silverlight. At some point in the future I intend on having a WPF one as well, although I'm mindful of duplication of effort with regards to WPF. There are already a number around. It would focus on complementing them not competing.

http://www.xamlsource.net/xamlcheatsheet

All feedback welcomed!

Update:
I've not renewed the domain name but wayback machine has a copy [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104133557/http://www.xamlsource.net/xamlcheatsheet).

Comment: Thank you for the easy to understand Cheat-Sheet! Can you please make it easier to print?

Comment: You're welcome. :) I hadn't thought of printing. What's the issue you are having with printing? Purely layout?

Comment: :) The scrollbars cause the data to get cut off.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to fix, I didn't see your comment. Have changed the format slightly so no scrollbars. Should print nicer now. Thanks!

Comment: The link is broken. :(

Comment: yeah, sry about that. I kind of let the domain name lapse. Not been working in the Silverlight space since Microsoft abandoned it. Perhaps it is on the waybackmachine? I'll check

Comment: Ok it's here... https://web.archive.org/web/20120104133557/http://www.xamlsource.net/xamlcheatsheet better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Refcardz have a free WPF cheat sheet.  You can view it online.  To download it as a PDF you need to register with the site.

http://blog.codebeach.com/2009/11/free-wpf-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a cheat sheet for my company. If you're interested, it's available here : http://objectis.ch/Blog/tabid/105/post/wpf-binding---cheat-sheet

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework 3.5 [Commonly Used Types and Namespaces poster](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/01/12/net-framework-3-5-namespace-poster-updated.aspx) has a section on common things in WPF as well as several other sections including Fundamentals.

It's available in a couple of different formats like XPS and PDF.  Perhaps it could be useful...

Comment: I already know about that poster, but that is not what I was looking for, I want a XAML cheat sheet not class library poster.

Answer (score 1):

I created a XAML Cheat Sheet not long after WPF first came out.  It's nice because it has a lot more than just data bindings.

https://www.mindfiretechnology.com/blog/archive/xaml-cheat-sheet/

Comment: i need to login?

Comment: @lizzy81 - Changed the URL. No login required.