# wpf - how can I create a dependency between expander inside datagrid and one of datagridrow properties

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dependencies, expander

This is a general question. And may not be specific to datagrids. How can i related 2 properties or 2 different UI Elements/controls

Like Each datagridRow has an Expander and i want the IsExpanded property to be dependent on datagridrow selected event .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative source binding can be used to bind two properties without referring to the source element by name.  This is especially useful is styles.

Here's an example of a ListBox with items that expand when selected.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander
                Header="{Binding}"
                IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}">
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding}" />
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <sys:String>a</sys:String>
    <sys:String>b</sys:String>
    <sys:String>c</sys:String>
    <sys:String>d</sys:String>

</ListBox>
```

When I need a fancy binding, I regularly use a cheat sheet posted by [Nir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3509/nir) on his [blog](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/02/wpf-xaml-data-binding-cheat-sheet.aspx) and referenced in the StackOverflow question [Is there a WPF Cheat Sheet outhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491312/is-there-a-wpf-cheat-sheet-outhere).

Here's the [cheat sheet direct link](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).

If you ever read this, thanks Nir.