# Looking for a chart of Wpf Bindings

Tags: wpf, syntax, charts, binding

I'm probably typical in being bewildered by the many syntaxes of Wpf binding. Does anyone know of a chart that lays out all the possibilities. Across one axis is all the variations of binding syntaxes (Static, Dynamic, Self, ...), the other axis are all the variations of scoping and type. The intersection of the axis show an example.

Surely someone, some author has done this, eh?

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491312/is-there-a-wpf-cheat-sheet-outhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Comment: it's far from being complete, many binding syntaxes are missing (binding to attached properties, to an index of a collection...)

Comment: @Thomas: Check the duplicate question for others.

Comment: Still haven't found one in chart form but they do exist in cheatsheet form. Similar question asking about a cheatsheet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491312/is-there-a-wpf-cheat-sheet-outhere

http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wpfcheatsheet.pdf

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/from-winform-to-wpf-a-quick-reference-guide/